# JhiAlertComponent, JhiAlertErrorComponent

Tags: javascript, alert, jhipster

I am trying to use these components `JhiAlertComponent`, `JhiAlertErrorComponent`. But it did not work. Can you help me?

```
<div class="modal-body">
        <jhi-alert-error></jhi-alert-error>
```

In my method

```
private onError(error) {
    //this.alertService.error(error.message, null, null);
    let err: JhiAlertErrorComponent = new JhiAlertErrorComponent(this.alertService, this.eventManager, this.translateService);
    err.addErrorAlert(error);
}
```

But the message is not rendered on UI.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the code that you sample is very little, but I can assume that you are doing a new module, in that case you need to import **JhiAlertComponen**t or **JhiAlertErrorComponent**,

Assuming that **Building** is the name of the project normally these are imported into
**BuildingSharedModule** which in turn is imported by **BuildingSharedCommonModule**, and this is imported into each component of Jhipster, so I suppose if it is a new component you may not have imported that component.

This is an example of module generated by jhipster:

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {BuildingcSharedModule, SharedPaginatorIntl} from '../../shared';
import {
    MatInputModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatFormFieldModule, MatPaginatorIntl
} from '@angular/material';
import { CdkTableModule} from '@angular/cdk/table';

import {
    ProductBceService,
    ProductBceComponent,
    ProductBceTableComponent,
    ProductBceModalComponent,
    ProductBceModalDeleteComponent,
    productRoute,
} from './';

const ENTITY_STATES = [
    ...productRoute,

];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BuildingcSharedModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(ENTITY_STATES, { useHash: true }),
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        FormsModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatDialogModule,
        MatCardModule,
        MatPaginatorModule,
        MatSortModule,
        MatTableModule,
        CdkTableModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        MatFormFieldModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        ProductBceComponent,
        ProductBceModalComponent,
        ProductBceModalDeleteComponent,
        ProductBceTableComponent,
    ],
    entryComponents: [
        ProductBceComponent,
        ProductBceModalComponent,
        ProductBceModalDeleteComponent,
        ProductBceTableComponent,
    ],
    providers: [
        ProductBceService,
        { provide: MatPaginatorIntl, useClass: SharedPaginatorIntl}
      ],
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class BuildingcProductBceModule {}
```